# PORT 1433 in use by LSASS.EXE, therefore cannot start SQL Server Service

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql

Sysinternals's TCPView shows that port 1433 is used by this OpSys process, both local and remote addresses contain my FQDN, which is a Win Server 2008-R2 fully patched, has someone faced such a situation.

I guess I can always change the sql port to say 1434, but it's been running fine for 2+ years with this setup.

TIA for your time.

Arturo Medina ###

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by adjusting the "random port" range defined in Windows.

Run this as administrator:

`netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=10000 num=1000
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport udp start=10000 num=1000`

Note that you will have to reboot the server to make the changes stick and to free up the port. You can adjust to your preferences.